# Lockout on a question and disinterested moderation

Tags: support

I seem to be in an [editing war with a moderator with more power than me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708082/why-would-i-use-git-commit-signing). As I stated in a comment after his title change:

> I usually don't complain about edits, but I don't like the title
>   change. I'm very interested in the specific problem commit signing is
>   solving, not a general "why should I do it"

I left the title change but followed with additional information to the question to ensure there was no confusion:

> The title was changed in an edit. I am not interested in "Why would I
>   use Git commit signing?" I am interested in "What problem does git
>   commit signing solve?"

The information was removed and the post was locked.

Would a dis-interested moderator please intercede.

I'm happy to take a decision by a dis-interested moderator.

Comment: [Comments archived](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/124236/discussion-on-question-by-jww-lockout-on-a-question-and-disinterested-moderation) - anyone interested in a mostly-irrelevant discussion of the question's topicality is welcome to [drop into chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124236/discussion-on-question-by-jww-lockout-on-a-question-and-disinterested-moderation).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Strictly-speaking, I'm not a moderator... But I'm *super* uninterested in this, so hopefully that'll make up for it.

**Don't get into an edit war.** That goes for both of you; as soon as you find yourself preparing to roll back a post a second time, it's time to think about trying something else. For example: make a different edit (one that finds a compromise or side-steps the disagreement), leave a comment addressing the other editor and requesting clarification, or just walk away for a while.

As Jeff wrote, years ago, in [In Defense of Editing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/),

> Do not fight an edit war over a crumb of bread -- there's nothing there worth fighting for! It's easier to just move on and get work done than create pain all out of proportion to the importance of the individual edit.

Comment: The compromise was made when I did not revert the edits; and the information was placed in the question to ensure there was no ambiguity. So, if the answer from a dis-interested mod [you] is *"do nothing"*, then I will accept it. Is that your answer?

Comment: Yeah, you put two sentences in there: one that clarified your problem (and could've easily resulted in a more specific 3rd variation on the title) and one that served no purpose other than noting that you were complaining about the title edit "which you usually don't". Could've really done without that. I suspect you have a good reason for usually not complaining, and that reason probably applied here too.

Answer (score 21):

You used an intentional misspelling of a word ("problèm" for "problem") in order to circumvent a restriction on using that word in titles. I came up with a title which is semantically no different from yours, but didn't contain an intentional misspelling.

The purpose of restricting words in titles isn't to fill our titles with random garbage characters and intentional misspellings. That much should be very obvious.

Then, you put a blob of meta information about my edit into your question.

> The information was removed...

The information was removed, with a series of comments explaining to you *why* it was removed, and asking you not to re-add it. You chose to repeatedly rollback my changes and reintroduce your comment.

> ...and the post was locked.

The post was locked until I was reasonably sure you had read my comment and were not going to continue rolling back my changes.

If you want to edit a specific, clarifying statement into your question, that's fine (though unnecessary, because as I said, your question already contains the exact phrase you're trying to game into the title). But adding a blob of meta information about the edit history of the question is not OK. We don't put that kind of info *in* the question.

As I've repeatedly said, there is no meaningful difference between our two titles:

> What problèm does git commit signing solve?
>
> Why would I use Git commit signing?

Assuming the answer to "which problem" is "problem X", the answer to "why use it" is still *"because problem x"*. For all intents and purposes, they are the same title, and will solicit the same answer.

Comment: As a bystander and fervent editor, I do somewhat agree with this, but it leaves a bad taste in my mouth.  I wonder if the question is too vague in that it's unclear as to why Git commit signing was deemed necessary.

Comment: @Makoto If true, that's an issue with *either wording*.  This edit has no effect on that problem with the question.

Comment: @Servy:  Hence why I'm thinking...perhaps the question should've been closed to prevent super-broad answers?  Give the OP a chance to pare down what it is they're asking?

Comment: @Makoto - Unfortunately, the question is locked :)

Comment: Question was unlocked half an hour ago, @jww.

Comment: @jww The question was unlocked before you even asked this meta question.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I was not aware it was unlocked. Should I delete the question or accept someone's answer?

Comment: You should accept mine, because I clearly care the least about it, @jww. Although posting this comment kinda undermines that statement. Dammit. Waffles.